# Why are all shoe objects in the ShoeCloset list underlined red? Am I doing something wrong with enums in class shoe?

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio, enums

Class ShoeList

```
 namespace ShoeClasses
 {
public class ShoeList
{

    public List<Shoe> shoeCloset;
    public ShoeList()
    {
        shoeCloset = new List<Shoe>();

        shoeCloset.Add(new Shoe()
        {
            Style = ShoeStyle.Sneakers,
            Color = "Green",
            Price = 50.99,
            Image = "Sneakers.jpg"
        });
 }
```

There's more Shoe objects in there, I just didn't want to put in too much code. So basically, there is a red line under "Shoe" (the one that says new Shoe()) when I hover over it it says "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'style' of 'Shoe.Shoe(ShoeStyle, string, double, string)'" Why is that and what must I do to fix it? I assigned a value to Style. Am I doing something wrong with Enums?

Class Shoe

```
 namespace ShoeClasses
 {
public enum ShoeStyle
{
    Clogs,
    Flipflops,
    Wingtips,
    Sneakers,
    Loafers,
    Sandals
}

public class Shoe
{

    public ShoeStyle Style { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }




    public Shoe(ShoeStyle style, string color, double price, string image)
    {
        Style = style; 
        Color = color;
        Price = price;
        Image = image;
    }

   }
```

Comment: `Shoe` doesn't have a parameterless constructor, so `new Shoe()` won't work (because you're trying to use a parameterless constructor). Since you've defined a constructor, I would suggest using that instead of the object initializer pattern, as you are currently using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Shoe class you have one constructor with 4 parameters.

```
public Shoe(ShoeStyle style, string color, double price, string image)
```

When you are initialising the Shoe object, you are passing 0 arguments when it's only set up to expect 4.

```
shoeCloset.Add(new Shoe()
```

Your choices to resolve this are:

1. Remove the parameters from the constructor and rely on setting the properties like you are doing.

```
public Shoe()
{
}
```

```
// this will work
shoeCloset.Add(new Shoe()
        {
            Style = ShoeStyle.Sneakers,
            Color = "Green",
            Price = 50.99,
            Image = "Sneakers.jpg"
        });
```

2. Pass your data into the Shoe initialisation:

```
public Shoe(ShoeStyle style, string color, double price, string image)
    {
        Style = style; 
        Color = color;
        Price = price;
        Image = image;
    }
```

```
shoeCloset.Add(new Shoe(ShoeStyle.Sneakers, "Green", 50.99, "Sneakers.jpg"));
```

3. Add in a parameterless constructor so that both options are avaialable

```
public Shoe()
    {
    }

public Shoe(ShoeStyle style, string color, double price, string image)
    {
        Style = style; 
        Color = color;
        Price = price;
        Image = image;
    }
```

```
// can now do both

shoeCloset.Add(new Shoe()
        {
            Style = ShoeStyle.Sneakers,
            Color = "Green",
            Price = 50.99,
            Image = "Sneakers.jpg"
        });

shoeCloset.Add(new Shoe(ShoeStyle.Sneakers, "Green", 50.99, "Sneakers.jpg"));
```